# send event id of eventClick to views.py Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm really new in Javascript and Fullcalendar and I need to know how to pass the event id of the clicked event (event_id) to the views.py. so for now I'm having that:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.3.0/main.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-GDey37RZAxFkpFeJorEUwNoIbkTwsyC736KNSYucu1WJWFK9qTdzYub8ATxktr6Dwke7nbFaioypzbDOQykoRg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarUI = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarUI, {
            eventClick: function (info) {
                
                var event_id = info.event.id;
                $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('show');
                $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                    'event_id': event_id
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('ooooooooookkkkkkk')
                    alert('Event: ' + info.event.id);
                },


            });
                },
            
            selectable: true,
            editable: true,
            displayEventTime: true,
            displayEventEnd: true,
            contentHeight: "auto",
            allDaySlot: false,
            initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'today',
                center: 'prev title next',
                right: 'dayGridMonth timeGridWeek'
            },
            
            // click in callendar
            dateClick: function(info) {
                date_clicked=info.dateStr;
                $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('show');
                //start_date.innerHTML = date_clicked


            },
            select: function(info) {
                //alert('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);
                date_from=info.startStr;
                date_to=info.endStr;
                $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('show');
                //start_date.innerHTML = date_from
                //end_date.innerHTML = date_to


            },

            views: {
                timeGridWeek: {
                    //titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }
                    columnHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', omitCommas: true }

                }
            },
            //slotLabelFormat: [{ month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }, { weekday: 'short' }],
            //slotLabelFormat: ['ddd D/M', 'H:mm'],
            events: [
                {% for reservation in reservations_api %}
                    {

                title: '{% for machine in machines %} {% if reservation.machine_id == machine.id %}  {{machine.machine_name}} {% endif %}  {% endfor %}  - {% for enterprise in enterprises %} {% if reservation.company_id == enterprise.id %}  {{enterprise.name}} {% endif %}  {% endfor %}  ',
                start: '{{ reservation.start_date }}',
                end: '{{ reservation.end_date  }}',
                color: '{% for enterprise in enterprises %} {% if reservation.company_id == enterprise.id %}  {{enterprise.color}} {% endif %}  {% endfor %}   ',
                //url: '',
                id: '{{ reservation.id }}',
                classNames: []

            },

            {% endfor %}
            ]



        });



    calendar.render();
    calendar.setOption('locale', 'fr')

    });
   </script>
```

I tried using Ajax but I'm getting an error, I'm not sure that it could works inside the eventClick,

the Ajax error is: `agenda:701 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`

Could you help me to solve this, please ! I will really appreciate your help :)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: To do something on the server from in-browser JavaScript you need AJAX / `$.ajax` / `fetch()`

Comment: Yes AJAX would work, why not? There's nothing special about eventClick. If you got an error, then try finding out what the error actually means, and fixing it, rather than making random assumptions. If you need some help with that, post the code you tried and the error you received here in your question, and we will try to assist.

Comment: @ADyson I just edited the question including the AJAX part and the error I'm having. Thanks a lot for all your help guys

Comment: Ok. So did you paste `$.ajax is not a function` into google? Because you'd have probably got a solution very quickly, before now. The issue will be either 1) you haven't included jQuery in your page, or 2) you've only used the "slim" version of jQuery which doesn't include any of the AJAX functionality. I'd guess maybe it's issue 2 because you already have other jQuery code in there, and you haven't reported any errors with that.

Comment: @ADyson , thanks a lot for answering. Yeah, I have googled it and I just verify again the cdn of Jquery that I have, I edited the answer with them. But still having the error :/ , that's why I thought it was the eventClick. Also, I use Ajax only for testing outside this eventClik and I have not this error message. so I don't know what could be the problem

Comment: You have 4 separate copies of jQuery referenced in your code there, and they're all different versions! That is inefficient, unnecessary, and likely to cause weird errors like the one you're experiencing. You only need one version - keeping the latest version (3.5.1 in your case) is usually the best choice. Remove those and see if you still have a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice, I'm really new with this, so it really helps me.  I have left only one version of Jquery `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`  and again the same error...

Comment: I made a little demo using your code, but replacing the AJAX links with the one you've shown in your last comment, and also using some test events instead of the python ones (but that's irrelevant to the issue): https://jsfiddle.net/a2yqeLpr/1/ . The error you're claiming does not occur. (I did get an error about `.modal()` not being a function, because the code you've shown doesn't include bootstrap, so I just commented those lines out - again not relevant to the error we're discussing. So assuming you removed the other jQuery links correctly, as I did, then your AJAX code is fine.

Comment: (You do have another problem though too - there are warnings that columnHeaderFormat is not a valid fullCalendar option - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc for a list of valid options).